# Unable To Contact Skype Technical Support

Tags: login, skype

I recently purchased some Skype credits and registered an account. I was able to begin using the service for the first day, but then it began alerting me that there were problems with my login and that they suspect it may be compromised. This is almost certainly due to me jumping around during normal travel and the use of VPNs. I have recently been informed that the account is locked and must be reset with a text message to my phone, however, Skype IS my new phone.

The problems:

1. There is no link for Technical Support (email, phone, chat) unless you are SIGNED IN, which I cannot do. Not sure why they would this, seems like a chicken and egg problem.
2. I do not have a seperate phone, nor do I want to have to procure one from a friend everytime this happens. This is the third time in as many days. The last lockout seems to be final as an email password reset no longer works around the problem.

Is there another way to reach them? Or should I consider my investment a waste and never do business with them again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unable To Contact Skype Technical Support. Technical Support (email, phone, chat) unless you are SIGNED IN, which I cannot do. Is there another way to reach them?**

*If all else fails, just [create a new Skype account](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12413/how-do-i-create-a-new-account-for-skype), contact support with that [free] new account and explain your situation, and perhaps they will be able to help you get this resolved.*

*You can contact them per [How do I contact Skype Customer Service?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1170/how-do-i-contact-skype-customer-service) and follow those instructions which I'll quote below, but essentially you'll go through the Customer Service method I suppose rather than directly to Technical Support.*

> ### [How do I contact Skype Customer Service?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1170/how-do-i-contact-skype-customer-service)
>
> [**What do I do if I am having problems signing
>   in?**](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1170/how-do-i-contact-skype-customer-service#)
>
> - Have you forgotten your username, password or have other problems    signing in? [We can help](https://support.skype.com/faq/FA109/).
> - If your account has been suspended or if you think it may have been    hacked or compromised, you can [recover your account](https://account.live.com/ResetPassword.aspx) online.
>
> ---
>
> [**How do I check the Community for
>   help?**](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1170/how-do-i-contact-skype-customer-service#)
>
> - If you can’t find the answer you’re looking for here on the Skype    Support website, the [Skype
>     Community](http://www.skype.com/go/community) has lots of helpful
>     information.    Start with a search for your question – chances are,
>     the answer’s    already there.
>
> <sub><sub>[Source](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1170/how-do-i-contact-skype-customer-service)</sub></sub>

Comment: Sadly, I did not think of going to the trouble of creating another account to deal with the original. That being said, Skype support still turned out to be as terrible as I have read, and was no help in this matter even after I was able to contact them. You still answered the question through, so you'll get what's coming to you. Thank you.